# How to turn a list of tuples into a single list

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I'm trying to turn a list of tuples into a single list with only the second value from each tuple.

```
targets :: [(a,b)] -> [a]
targets (x:xs) = [snd(x)] ++ targets xs
```

This is what I have so far but it is not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: in `[(a,b)]`, the second value's type is `b`.

Comment: Every recursive algorithm like this needs a terminating clause, that is, when it does NOT call itself.

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes in your code. The first of which, GHC will warn you about:

```
<interactive>:3:30: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘b’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          targets :: forall a b. [(a, b)] -> [a]
        at <interactive>:2:1-25
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          targets :: forall a b. [(a, b)] -> [a]
        at <interactive>:2:1-25
      Expected type: [b]
        Actual type: [a]
```

The second element of the tuple is of type `b` (since you declare the tuple to be `(a, b)`), so the resulting array should not be `[a]` (what GHC calls the actual type), but it should be `[b]` (what GHC calls the expected type). Then, you're also missing a case. What if it's called on the empty array? Then it won't match `(x:xs)`, so you should add a special case for that (also remember that every recursive function should have a base case):

```hs
targets :: [(a, b)] -> [b]
-- using x:y instead of [x] ++ y since they do the same thing
targets (x:xs) = snd x:targets xs
-- the base case for when nothing matches
targets _ = []
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a *mapping* where for each 2-tuple, you take the second element, hence we can use [**`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map):

```
targets :: [(a,b)] -> [b]
targets = map snd
```

Notice that the return type is `[b]`: a list of `b`s, not `a`s. Your type for a [**`Graph`**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64813330/67579) however has as type `[(Node a, [Int])]`, so you will need to concatenate these lists together.